# Can You Place a Debug Breakpoint for System Functions in PHPUnit/XDebug?

Tags: php, debugging, phpunit, xdebug

In PHPUnit, I would like to put a breakpoint for a built-in function. Is this possible and how?

For example, I would like to break everytime `ob_end_clean`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not an easy way I know of, unless this is a function, and in your code you call the function.  Then, you put a break point on that line in the function.

```
function BufferClean()
{
    ...   // Some Common Code
    ob_end_clean;
}

//Main code
...
BufferClean();
...
...
...
BufferClean();
...
```

In this case, the break point is in the function which is called instead of ob_end_clean directly, allowing you to place one break point.  It is also easy to change the code since global replace in the source code could be used.